# Regression: Is $\overline{y}=\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{i=1} y_i$ or $\hat{\beta_0}+\hat{\beta_1}\bar{x}$

Tags: regression, linear-regression

As the question suggests, I'm used to $\overline{y}$ being $\frac{1}{n}\sum^n _{i=1} y_i$ but in the following proof, this seems to be not the case.

$$SS_{reg}=\sum^n_{i=1}(\hat{y}_i-\overline{y})^2=\sum^n_{i=1}[(\hat{\beta}_0+\hat{\beta}_1x_i)-(\hat{\beta}_0+\hat{\beta}_1\bar{x})]^2$$
$$=\sum^n_{i=1}\hat{\beta}_1^2(x_i-\bar{x})^2 = \hat{\beta}_1^2\sum^n_{i=1}(x_i-\bar{x})^2 =\hat{\beta}_1^2S_{xx}$$

and this result works out just fine.
Is there some proof that $\overline{y}=\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{i=1} y_i=\hat{\beta_0}+\hat{\beta_1}\bar{x}$  ?

In this case, I'm assuming that $\overline{x}=\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{i=1}x_i $

Comment: Shouldnt $\bar y = \sum y_i  /n$?

Comment: Also, it is a property of the least-squares regression line that it goes through the point $(\bar x, \bar y)$.

Comment: It is well known that $\overline{x}= \color{blue}{\frac1n}\cdot \sum\limits^n_{i=1}x_i$

Comment: @Just_to_Answer Thanks, corrected

Comment: @callculus Sorry for that typo, corrected

Comment: @Just_to_Answer
I understand, but is there some formal proof for that? That the usual definition is equal to the property you mentioned?

Comment: @Malcolm: Sure, one can derive the formulae for $\hat \beta_0$ and $\hat \beta_1$ directly from the minimization of the least-squares (either using calculus or linear-algebra) and get $\hat \beta_0 = \bar y - \hat \beta_1 \bar x$.

Comment: @Just_to_Answer I understand, thank you for the insightful response!

Comment: If you look at the derivation of the estimates, the first derivative will give you that the deviation of $y_i$ from the estimated y has average zero. Now use that to take averages on both sides of the equation.

Comment: @Malcolm: You are welcome. When I say to use calculus, make sure to have only one "l" on the first "l" : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_i +\epsilon_i$, you have that the OLS estimators are 
$$
\hat{\beta_1}= \frac{\sum(y_i - \bar{y})(x_i - \bar{x})}{\sum(x_i - \bar{x})^2}\, ,\qquad \hat{\beta}_0 = \bar{y}- \hat{\beta}_1\bar{x}\, , 
$$
hence, if you plugging-in $x_0 = \bar{x}$ in the estimated equation, you'll have that 
$$
\hat{y}(x_0 = \bar{x})=\hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1\bar{x}=\bar{y}- \hat{\beta}_1\bar{x}+ \hat{\beta}_1\bar{x} = \bar{y}. 
$$